# How can I print a specific Index of an Array on the DOM after a button click redirecting to a different HTML file?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I am using a Bootstrap Carousel, but the slides of the carousel are generated through `DOM` by looping through an array called "Capris".
There is a button that displays on each slide that is also specific to each index.

What I am trying to do is when a User clicks on one of the buttons, it redirects them to a different HTML file and prints to `DOM` that same index, just on the other HTML page.

I managed to do everything except having that index print to `DOM` on the second HTML file. Here is a snippet of my code for the carousel and the button's event listener:

```js
const buyCapriBttn = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < capris.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector(`#${capris[i].name}`).addEventListener('click', function () {generateProduct(capris[i])});
  }
}

const capriCarousel = () => {
  let domString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < capris.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      domString += `
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="${capris[i].imageUrl}" alt="Capri 1">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a id="${capris[i].name}" class="btn btn-primary capri-btn" href="/capris.html" role="button">Buy ${capris[i].name}</a>
      </div>
      <p class="capri-description">${capris[i].description}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    } else if (i >= 1) {
      domString += `
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="${capris[i].imageUrl}" alt="Capri 1">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a id="${capris[i].name}" class="btn btn-primary capri-btn" href="/capris.html" role="button">Buy ${capris[i].name}</a>
        </div>
        <p class="capri-description">${capris[i].description}</p>
      </div>
      `;
    } else;
  }
  printToDom("#carousel-items", domString);
  buyCapriBttn();
}
```

When the button is clicked, it runs the `generateProduct` function for that index. Here is a snippet of that function that is run:

```js
const generateProduct = (selectedPants) => {
  domString = '';
  console.log(selectedPants);
  for (let i = 0; i < capris.length; i++) {
    if (capris[i] === selectedPants) {
    domString += `
    <div id="caprisDom">
      <img id="buycaprispic" src="${capris[i].imageUrl}">
      <div id="nameandrating">
        <h5 id="buycaprisname">${capris[i].name}</h5><h2>☆☆☆☆☆</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="caprisinfobox">
        <p id="caprisinfo">${capris[i].description}</p>
        <div class="sizeandprice">
          <div id="sizeselector">
            <label id="sizelabel">Size:</label>
            <select name="sizelist" id="size">
            </select>
          </div>
          <h3 id="price">$${capris[i].price}</h3>
        </div>
        <button id="cartbutton">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
    }
  }
  printToDom('#caprismain', domString);
}
```

I have a `printToDom` function that prints to those ids if you need that as well.

**NOTE: In this exercise, I am trying to *not* use JQuery**

Any thoughts and help are much appreciated!

Comment: You'd have to use a query string/ session/local storage or some PHP to carry it over to the new page, as it'll reload and you'll lose that variable in the JS.

Comment: @JoelHager Thank you! Would there by chance be a way to do it without jquery or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is all you need the *index* position of the item? I'd probably add it dynamically in the `a` declaration. Something like `<a id="${capris[i].name}" class="btn btn-primary capri-btn" href="/capris.html?index=${i}" role="button">Buy ${capris[i].name}</a>`

So it should look like this:

```
const capriCarousel = () => {
  let domString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < capris.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      domString += `
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="${capris[i].imageUrl}" alt="Capri 1">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a id="${capris[i].name}" class="btn btn-primary capri-btn" href="/capris.html?index=${i}" role="button">Buy ${capris[i].name}</a>
      </div>
      <p class="capri-description">${capris[i].description}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    } else if (i >= 1) {
      domString += `
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="${capris[i].imageUrl}" alt="Capri 1">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a id="${capris[i].name}" class="btn btn-primary capri-btn" href="/capris.html?index=${i}" role="button">Buy ${capris[i].name}</a>
        </div>
        <p class="capri-description">${capris[i].description}</p>
      </div>
      `;
    } else;
  }
  printToDom("#carousel-items", domString);
  buyCapriBttn();
}
```

Then, in the other page, in your js, you'd *grab* the query select using URLSearchParams like so:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('index');
```

Comment: Amazing. This worked for me! Thank you so much, I spent all weekend trying to get this to work.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted! :)